# Is it possible to provide free taster period within Non-Renewing Subscription for iPhone apps?

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store, subscription

The app we are creating delivers information which updates on a daily basis, how to provide a free taster is unclear to me. Can you help?

Info on Non-Renewing Subscription from p149 of the iTC developer Guide, p151 states Inn-App purchase cannot be free.

https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/iTunesConnect_DeveloperGuide.pdf

■ Non-Renewing Subscriptions have been used in the past for services with a limited duration. An example of this would be a magazine or newspaper that requires users to renew their own subscriptions. Non-renewing subscriptions can still be offered, but auto-renewable subscriptions are now preferred for the following reasons:

- When creating an auto-renewable subscription, you can easily set up the various durations that you want to offer. Non-renewing subscriptions do not have this feature, so you must provide the information some other way. As this is often done in the display name, you end up with a separate listing for every possible duration. By contrast, auto-renewable subscriptions allow you to have a single listing where the user simply chooses one of the durations that you offer.
- Because a non-renewing subscription requires a user to renew each time, your app must contain code that recognizes when the subscription is due to expire. It must also prompt the user to purchase a new subscription. An auto-renewable subscription eliminates these steps.
- As part of iOS, an auto-renewable subscription will automatically be delivered to all devices associated with the user’s Apple ID. To make device-syncing available for a non-renewing subscription, you would have to create your own delivery system.

Answer (score 2):

You could sell your app for free on the store.  Then offer a non-renewing subscription, but only show the option to the user after a month has passed (or whatever period you choose).  You should administer the subscription from your own server so that you can verify receipts, and keep track of expiration dates even if a user deletes your app and re-installs it.  Using your server will also give you a way to sync the subscription across all the devices a user owns (which is required by Apple. They essentially insist that you implement an **optional** username/password system to allow a user to restore their subscription to other devices).

**Warning:** Don't use the words 'trial' or 'demo' in your app or description.  This is against Apple's policies.  Also, don't make your app dead if the user chooses not to buy a subscription after a month.  This will also likely get you rejected. You should continue to provide some functionality.

Comment: I also thought trials are not allowed but here is an app that does that - 15 uses of premium feature before IAP, and it talks about it in description: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id441912305 - have guidelines changed?

Comment: I don't think the guidelines have changed. I think it's more likely that Apple just missed it in their review.

Answer (score 0):

Distribute a free lite version with function limit, or try in app purchase.